# What you think about printing the string length without strlen() or loops in C? Is that possible?

Tags: c, string, scanf, string-length, strlen

I was asked to fill in the blanks in order to make the program print the length of the string. The blank space is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
char str[101];
int strlen;
scanf(          );
printf("%d", strlen); 
return 0;
}
```

Now, I want to fill the blanks in the `scanf()` area. I think neither the `strlen` nor the loops can be used for this.
What should I code to print the length?

Comment: Have you researched what `scanf` does and how it works? Hint: read about its `return` value

Comment: @JohnDoe: The return value of `printf( "%s", str );` may be helpful in this situation, but not the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: As the name of a commonly used standard library function, `strlen` should not be used as name for a variable.

Comment: *Now, I want to...* Nobody "wants" to do this sort of thing. :-)  Is this from a puzzle/contest site, or homework?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel my bad, I haven't used `scanf` in a long time and somehow remembered  it returned the number of characters read not the number of fields successfully assigned

Answer (score 6):

It seems what you need is the following

```
scanf( "%100s%n", str, &strlen );
```

Pay attention to that using the name `strlen` for the variable that corresponds to the standard string function `strlen` is a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility (though not quite exactly filling in your blanks) is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[101];
    int len;
    printf("enter a string: "); fflush(stdout);
    if(scanf("%100s", str) == 1) {
        printf("the length of the string \"");
        len = printf("%s", str);
        printf("\" is %d\n", len);
    }
}
```